# I am trying to retrieve email of current user logged in and place their email/identifier into a field called userEmail

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve email of current user and put it into my attendance collection after a scan has taken place. What I have done is code to find current user's email and passed in as a paramenter. This does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
private void barcodeRecognition(Bitmap photo) {
    FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(photo);
    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getVisionBarcodeDetector();
    Task<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>> result = detector.detectInImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> barcodes) {

                    for (FirebaseVisionBarcode barcode: barcodes) {
                        Rect bounds = barcode.getBoundingBox();
                        Point[] corners = barcode.getCornerPoints();

                        final String rawValue = barcode.getRawValue();
                        int valueType =  barcode.getValueType();


                        mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        // TRY LINKING TO userUID on Attendance on Firebase console
                        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        final String user = currentUser.getUid(); // USED TO GET CURRENT USER UID OF PERSON LOGGED IN
                        final String user1 = currentUser.getEmail(); // USING TO RETRIEVE EMAIL AS FIELD IN ATTENDANCE TO VIEW
                        //THIS CAN BE SET TO .getUserName() or getEmail() depending on preference

                        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                        final String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());

                        final FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        final DocumentReference docRef = rootRef.collection("Session").document(rawValue);
                        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                    if (document.exists()) {

                                        Date timeToCheck = calendar.getTime();
                                        Session session = document.toObject(Session.class);
                                        Date startTime = session.getStartTime();
                                        Date endTime = session.getEndTime();
                                        if (timeToCheck.after(startTime) && (timeToCheck.before(endTime))) {

                                            Attendance attendance = new Attendance(rawValue, user, time, user1);
                                            attendanceRef3.add(attendance);
                                            Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this, "Your attendance has been recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this, "Attendance attempt invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(StudentAccount.this, "Session does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: user1 is being used to store current users email also

Comment: What doesn't work about this code? If you step through it with a debugger, which line gives you a different result than you expected?

Comment: The user email does not update on the firestore database. When I pass in user1 I am hoping to retrieve the current email of whoever is logged in and add it to my attendance collection. It adds the current user and the other fields but not the email. Is there any reason for this Frank?

Comment: Does `user1` have the value you expect it to have? Does `onComplete` get called? If so, what's the value of `task.isSuccessful()`?